# How to know more about my tax situation in the States

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company, irs

I've been part of an LLC that actually never started to operate. My management opened it, and then closed it after 2 years.

No income, no business bank account, no EIN. Basically it was just registered to the California Secretary of State, and nothing else.

How can I reach the IRS with my SSN and ask them if there is something I owe, and if my American tax situation is completely clean?

Comment: These aren't taxable events. But the real answer is to get an accountant.

Comment: How were you part of it? Did you own shares in the company or have some other kind of relationship there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LLC (not you) is probably in debt to the California FTB. Any LLC registered in California must pay at least $800 a year, until it is officially dissolved (i.e.: notice of cancellation/dissolution properly filed with the California Secretary of State).

The FTB *may* come after members (including you) personally, if it can prove that the failure to pay was due to your negligence. Talk to a CA-licensed EA/CPA about how to resolve this.

Otherwise, at least from what you've described, there were no other taxable events. LLC is a disregarded entity, so the IRS doesn't care about it much anyway (unless someone was stupid enough to elect it to be taxed as a corporation, that is).

Keep in mind that when in doubt - you are always better off with a professional (a CPA/EA licensed in your State) advice.